# grunt-contrib-requirejs doesn't track all dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, knockout.js, requirejs

I'm trying to do r.js optimisation. I have this example project https://github.com/noppanit/requirejs-optimization-example built with knockoutjs which I use grunt-contrib-requirejs. Everything works fine. But I think grunt-contrib-requirejs doesn't track all of my dependencies

Here's my Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                    options: {
                        baseUrl: "./js",
                    paths: {
                        'knockout': 'vendors/knockout/knockout-3.0.0'
                    },
                        mainConfigFile: "js/config.js",
                        name: "application",
                        out: "js/optimized.js"
                    }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);
};
```

Here's how I include my optimized file

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        Name: <input type="text" data-bind="value: name"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        Surname: <input type="text" data-bind="value: surname" />
    </div>

    <span data-bind="text: fullname"></span>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/require.js" data-main="js/optimized">
</script>

</html>
```

Here's my config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.0',
        'knockout': 'vendors/knockout/knockout-3.0.0',
        'main-viewmodel': 'viewmodels/main_viewmodel',
        'main-call': 'viewmodels/main_call',
    }

});
```

And here's my application.js

```
require(['config'], function() {
    require(['main-call','knockout']);
});
```

After I run `grunt`

Here's what I get from optimized.js

```
require.config({baseUrl:"./js",paths:{jquery:"vendors/jquery/jquery-1.11.0",knockout:"vendors/knockout/knockout-3.0.0","main-viewmodel":"viewmodels/main_viewmodel","main-call":"viewmodels/main_call"}}),define("config",function(){}),require(["config"],function(){require(["main-call","knockout"])}),define("application",function(){});
```

which looks like just the combination of config.js and application.js I expect all the javascript files including requirejs and knockoutjs will be included as well. So the browser would just make one call to get the optimized javascript.

Comment: How does it not work? Do you get an error on the console?

Comment: when I changed to optimized version, the it's like the app wasn't working at all.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: explicitly declare the dependencies

```
require(['jquery', 'knockout', 'main-call', 'config'], function($, ko, mainCall) {
    //the code
});
```

Option 2: add dependencies to the included list

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        requirejs: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    baseUrl: "./js",
                    paths: {
                        'knockout': 'vendors/knockout/knockout-3.0.0'
                    },
                    mainConfigFile: "js/config.js",
                    include: ['jquery', 'knockout', 'main-viewmodel', 'main-call'],
                    name: "application",
                    out: "js/optimized.js"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-requirejs');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['requirejs']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are optimizing your config file, but the config file doesn't have any dependencies.  It's the only file it optimizes.

Usually at the end of the config file, you require the main file (in your case, main-call, knockout). Then the optimization should happen properly.  The application.js is not being read